# MySQL - Selecting rows where fields not equal

Tags: mysql, select

I have a little problem with an SQL query: I have 'TableA' with a field 'TableA.b' that contains an ID for 'TableB'. I want to select all rows from 'TableB' that don't have an ID that equals any field 'TableA.b'. With other words, I need every row from TableB that's not referred to by any row from TableA in field .
I tried a Query like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableB.* FROM TableA, TableB Where TableA.b != TableB.ID
```

But the result contains a row that is also returned by the negation, i.e. where both fields have the same value. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did any of the submitted answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [LEFT (or RIGHT) JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

```
SELECT TableB.* FROM TableA 
  LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.b = TableB.ID
    WHERE TableA.b IS NULL
```

While it's possible to do the same with a subquery as in some of the otehr answers. A join will often be [faster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rewriting-subqueries.html).

> A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because
>   the server might be able to optimize it better—a fact that is not
>   specific to MySQL Server alone. Prior to SQL-92, outer joins did not
>   exist, so subqueries were the only way to do certain things. Today,
>   MySQL Server and many other modern database systems offer a wide range
>   of outer join types.

Answer (score 1):

First, select all ids from `TableA`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b FROM TableA
```

Then use that result to select all rows in `TableB` that have an id that does not exist in this set by using the above query as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT b FROM TableA)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  SELECT TableB.* FROM TableB
  WHERE ID NOT IN
       (SELECT b from TableA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN` in SELECT Query.

```
SELECT * FROM TableB t1 WHERE t1.ID NOT IN (SELECT t2.b FROM TableA t2);
```

Comment: This might be the solution but it seems like I'm getting an empty result if the inner select result contains NULL.

Comment: `@user1563232` that not possible. Inner Select either give Empty or Number of rows. NULL is not possible in above query..

Comment: if you want data of tableB than no need to make inner or left join with tableA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use right join also.
Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableB.* FROM  tablea RIGHT JOIN TableB ON TableA.b = Tableb.ID WHERE TableA.B IS NULL
```